# How do I make space between the thumbnails in the gallery and it's the same in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, gallery, thumbnails

I have a sliding gallery with thumbnails.I try to make the distance between the thumbnails equal (about 1-2 pixels) and this distance to be the same in each browser.
I tried different codes but it didn't work.
I tried margin, padding, bootstrap table column, different classes for different sizes but I did not get an equal distance or I'm doing something wrong.
How do I make equal space between the thumbnails in the gallery and it's the same in all browsers?

```css
/* 
 *  Core Owl Carousel CSS File
 *  v1.3.3
 */

/* clearfix */
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}


/* display none until init */
.owl-carousel{
    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}


.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer.autoHeight{
    -webkit-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: height 500ms ease-in-out;
}
    

.owl-carousel .owl-item {                   
        float: left;
        justify-content:center;
        margin:1.875em;
        display:flex;
        
}


.owl-controls .owl-page,
.owl-controls .owl-buttons div{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.owl-controls {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/* mouse grab icon */
.grabbing { 
    cursor:url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}

/* fix */
.owl-carousel  .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel  .owl-item{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title></title>

    </head>       
   <body>
    
    <!-- ***** Header Area Start ***** -->
    <header class="header-area header-sticky">
       
        
    </header>
   
     
    <!-- ***** Content Gallery ********************************************************************************** -->
  
                  <section id="screenshot">

               <!-- Screenshot Owl Carousel -->
               <div class="owl-carousel">     

                   <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s" >
                   <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LMDoTaFIRsc6thppojY-XYmAl3oCP10c5kE3QdeUr4Gk4L8OqEEAxfw4ECEfswW6EdJ48YomaXj7BAjzyNjL" class="image-popup">
                   <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LMDoTaFIRsc6thppojY-XYmAl3oCP10c5kE3QdeUr4Gk4L8OqEEAxfw4ECEfswW6EdJ48YomaXj7BAjzyNjL" class="img-responsive div2" alt="screenshot"> 
                   </a>
                   </div>
 <p></p>
                        <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">  
                                <a href="images/2.jpg" class="image-popup">
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/5b/85/635b85d1013a50df7aae1b8e21d1a445.jpg" class="img-responsive div1" alt="screenshot">
                                </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                                <a href="images/3.jpg" class="image-popup">
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/5b/85/635b85d1013a50df7aae1b8e21d1a445.jpg" class="img-responsive div1" alt="screenshot">
                                </a>
                        </div>                                

                        <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                                <a href="images/4.jpg" class="image-popup">
                                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LMDoTaFIRsc6thppojY-XYmAl3oCP10c5kE3QdeUr4Gk4L8OqEEAxfw4ECEfswW6EdJ48YomaXj7BAjzyNjL" class="img-responsive div2" alt="screenshot">
                                </a>
                        </div>
<p></p>
                        <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                                <a href="images/5.jpg" class="image-popup">
                                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LMDoTaFIRsc6thppojY-XYmAl3oCP10c5kE3QdeUr4Gk4L8OqEEAxfw4ECEfswW6EdJ48YomaXj7BAjzyNjL" class="img-responsive div2" alt="screenshot">
                                </a>
                        </div>
<p></p>
                    <div class="item col-md-3 col-sm-3 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.9s">
                         <a href="images/6.jpg" class="image-popup">
                              <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LMDoTaFIRsc6thppojY-XYmAl3oCP10c5kE3QdeUr4Gk4L8OqEEAxfw4ECEfswW6EdJ48YomaXj7BAjzyNjL" class="img-responsive div2" alt="screenshot">
                         </a>
                    </div>
               </div>

</section>      

                <!-- Footer -->
                    <footer id="footer">                          
                    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your images are not public so the visual output is broken.

Comment: what i have to do

Comment: Please do not try to hack SO by not posting code

Comment: I made a snippet - please fix it so it is a [mcve] with relevant libraries

Answer (score 0):

you can use margin bottom or margin left in respect of the side from which you want distance.if it works let me know

```css
{
margin-bottom:2px;
margin-left:2px;
}
```

property like this

Comment: there is no difference in distance unfortunately

Comment: @Vall let me know what exactly you are trying to do or what you want

Answer (score 0):

I make it with changing

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item {                  
    float: left;
    justify-content:center;
    margin:1.875em;
    display:flex;
    margin-right: 0.49%; -specific for every page
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

}

and add container in `<div class="owl-carousel">`

Now i have to try to expand "container" with the width of the any desktop.
Any ideas?